# how to dismiss scrollview controller from scroll view's child view

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

i am using a scrollview and i adding subviews to scrollview into code behind. And Now when i click a button from **subview** controller, i want to close my **scrollviewcontroller**(parent). my scrollviewcontroller paging enabled. And all pages using same class.(mySubviewController)

i am using this but doesnt work;

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or this;

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

how to do this?

---***edit***----

```
[main screen]---> [scrollview](srolling sub views)

[subview]((x button)-(y button)-(z button))
[subview]((x button)-(y button)-(z button))
[subview]((x button)-(y button)-(z button))
[subview]((x button)-(y button)-(z button))
```

when i click z button into anysubview , i want to close scrollview...

my scrollview's code;

```
   - (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < 0) return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
        controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: no, i want close screen.

Comment: why don't you use popViewController?

Comment: i am a new iphone developer. i just want to learn "how to achieve scrollViewController from into its child view?"

Comment: Are you sure you're really meaning scrollViewCONTROLLER not just scrollView?

Comment: my .h page start like..;

@interface ScrollViewWithPagingViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {

Comment: i use UIScrollView in xib file

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i'm understanding you exactly but maybe you should try

```
[[self parentViewController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: how about [self sendSubviewToBack:scrollView];

Comment: scrollView is not public, can i use it from subView's code behind?

Comment: i am working for close it from MyViewController's code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[self.subview.superview removeFromSuperview];
```

From what I get, your subview should be your ViewController's view.

Comment: Subview is your view, in this case, I think it is MyViewController's view.

Comment: already i need to write into MyViewController this code, and self = MyViewController but i didnt see .superview

Comment: OK write this: [controller.view.superview removeFromSuperview] or this: [self.view.superview removeFromSuperview]